# Detect if text has overflowed

Tags: javascript

How can you detect if text has overflown? For example, the following text is longer than it's div container allows. How can I detect this in javascript?

```
<div style="max-width: 100px; white-space:nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
</div>
```

Answer (score 167, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can try comparing the div's width to its scrollWidth.

```
if ($('#div-id')[0].scrollWidth >  $('#div-id').innerWidth()) {
    //Text has over-flown
}
```

Comment: I had to also use `innerWidth()` instead of `width()` to account for paddings.

Comment: I use the same technique, but comparing the `scrollHeight` against `innerHeight()`

Comment: Edited to use innerWidth() instead of width()

Comment: AND...
It is always better to use "jQuery" instead of "$"... :)

Comment: @TheCuBeMan: The actual best approach is to wrap the jQuery code in a closure taking `$` and pass it `jQuery` as an argument. This is what jQuery Core does. e.g. `(function ($) { // code })(jQuery);`

Comment: @wizonesolutions but what happens when you have other JS framework(s) on the same page/site and it already uses the $ sign?? I still say that it is best to use the jQuery object name in order to avoid collisions etc.

Comment: @TheCuBeMan But that pattern does use jQuery. It aliases it to $ in the closure scope. Collision-free.

Comment: @wizonesolutions Let me ask you this - in this way, does it mean that the $ character will be used to refer to the jQuery object (and functionality)? because if it does, then there's the possibility of the collision. Let's say that there is another framework that is already utilizing this character for its purposes, then this code will override it and create the problem. Even if jQuery is referenced before the other framework, then the latter will be the one to utilize the $ character, therefore the code did nothing. Why not just always rely on "jQuery" as the only reference to its library?...

Comment: @TheCuBeMan But only within the IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression, the pattern I showed above). Outside of the IIFE, if you have called `jQuery.noConflict()`, there is no problem. The closure receives `jQuery` as its argument and it takes a parameter called `$`, so `$` within the IIFE points to `jQuery`. This is compatible with your advice always to use `jQuery`; it simply aliases it. It doesn't affect the global scope. One can also pass references to other libraries to the IIFE by adding more parameters and arguments.

Comment: @TheCuBeMan 

There are several assumptions I've made in my solution. i.e.:

1) The jQuery object has been assigned to $ in someway, such as being passed into the scope or being set at the global scope.

2) That the selector used returns one and exactly one element. Otherwise the array index used (0) creates problems when the object doesn't exist, or when there are multiple matched elements (this snippet only considers the first element matched).

I admit that, in an effort to provide a clear and concise solution to the question, solving these issues are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: doesn't work in ie11

Comment: Can you be more specific @DrewB

Comment: It worked great in chrome, firefox and iOS but not on ie11.  Was a month ago so I don't recall which part of the solution wasn't working.  I ended up using the top answer from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143815/how-to-determine-using-javascript-if-html-element-has-overflowing-content/143889#143889 instead.

Comment: If you can reproduce the problem please provide a jsfiddle and I can update my answer

Comment: Actually should use `.clientWidth`. All the rest are not accurate. `.width`, `.innerWidth`, etc.. always return a number that is lower than `.scrollWidth`.

Comment: I second @LiranFunaro's suggestion. In my case `innerWidth()` returned a float, which deviated `0.072` from `scrollWidth`, therefore the statement would always evaluate to true.

Answer (score 20):

You can detect whether text will fit **before** you display the element. So you can use this function which doesn't require the element to be on screen.

```
function textWidth(text, fontProp) {
    var tag = document.createElement('div')
    tag.style.position = 'absolute'
    tag.style.left = '-99in'
    tag.style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap'
    tag.style.font = fontProp
    tag.innerHTML = text

    document.body.appendChild(tag)
    var result = tag.clientWidth
    document.body.removeChild(tag)
    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
if (textWidth('Text', 'bold 13px Verdana') > elementWidth) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me when scrollWidth is zero, which seems to happen sometimes (haven't figured out why...)

Comment: So very helpful! I basically just slapped together my own, simplified version of [Fitty.js](https://github.com/rikschennink/fitty), to loop through a page's elements and if any are larger than their container, decrease the font 1px at a time until it fits.  :-)

Comment: worked just fine for me

Answer (score 6):

jQuery plugin for checking if text has overflown, not written very well, but works as it suppose to be working. Posting this because I didn't find a working plugin for this anywhere.

```
jQuery.fn.hasOverflown = function () {
   var res;
   var cont = $('<div>'+this.text()+'</div>').css("display", "table")
   .css("z-index", "-1").css("position", "absolute")
   .css("font-family", this.css("font-family"))
   .css("font-size", this.css("font-size"))
   .css("font-weight", this.css("font-weight")).appendTo('body');
   res = (cont.width()>this.width());
   cont.remove();
   return res;
}
```

Comment: nice plugin, but the correct past tense of 'overflow' is 'overflowed' =)

Comment: This works pretty well! Could you please explain how it works? As far as I can tell, this is better than the `isEllipsisActive` function you can find here on SO because it works even with some edge cases when the width of the overflowed text is the same as the width of the text without `overflow:hidden;` and `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Comment: This works, but only for elements that contain single line of text. For elements with a fixed width that span multiple lines, modify this function to test for height instead of width.

Answer (score 1):

For illustrative purposes let's say your div has `id="d"`, then you could do:

```
var d = document.getElementById('d'),
    dWider;
d.style.maxWidth = '9999em';
d.style.overflow = 'visible';
dWider = d.offsetWidth > 100;
d.style.maxWidth = '100px';
d.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Then the var `dWider` will be true if the text overflows and false if it doesn't.