# Chrome search feature (ctrl+f) finds hidden text ( but it's invisible! )

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, styling, ellipsis

Look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t5eUe/).

Enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search "gets" ...

For me Chrome finds invisible text from this text: `A long option that gets cut off`

It's reproduced on Linux/Ubuntu 12.04 Chrome Version 31.0.1650.63

**HTML**

```
<!--works for a div-->
<div>
    A long option that gets cut off
</div>

<!--but not for a select-->
<select>
    <option>One - A long option that gets cut off</option>
    <option>Two - A long option that gets cut off</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select {
    width:100px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

div {
    border-style:solid; 
    width:100px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

How do I show the text when it is found on a page, rather than a blank chunk of whitespace, highlighted by the browser?

Comment: How do you not see the problem @DoorknobofSnow? It's that `ctrl-f` finds text that is supposed to be hidden. The question is presumably how to prevent this.

Comment: Looks like there are **2 Questions** here 1) ctrl + F finds hidden text on a div - but it's invisible (a blank space is highlighted) and 2) ctrl + f *doesn't find* the hidden text of a selct/options element

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Unfortunately, this is a known bug in Chrome.

Bug Reports:

- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93709
- https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13563

It happens because of `text-overflow: ellipsis;` the bug report says.

**No solution to the bug, since 2010!**

---

### Avoid the problem...

This is not as pretty, but it works in light of the known issue:

```
select {
    width:100px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
}

div {
    border-style:solid; 
    width:100px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap;
    /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
}
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/t5eUe/228/

[image]

---

### Or work around it...

Use JavaScript to detect the overflow, and insert an ellipsis yourself, as an image ( or a block of text ) on the right and/or left of the div, or on the inside of the right side ( with a higher `z-index` ), etc:

- [Detect if text has overflown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown)

Comment: Thanks, actually we cant get the same result by adding display: -webkit-box http://jsfiddle.net/c96jL/ but I need these 3 dots :)

Comment: Updated my answer for you, with an unorthodox fix, otherwise you're out of luck @YuriyBugryn

Comment: Thanks, @digitalextremist. I will use JS for fixing it.

Comment: Since the chrome bug was closed, I re-opened it at: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1067893

Comment: Ironically, this "bug" (anomaly?) is present on every StackOverflow page when you're logged in and try to search for your own username on a page to see if you've already commented on something hahahah.

Comment: @ubershmekel I was gonna chime in on your bug (which is still Open and untriaged), but that site still prints user emails partially for some unfathomable reason. Why anyone would be OK have even part of their email publicly scannable on a forum like that, I don't know.

Comment: 13 years and it is still not fixed. I'm losing all hope it ever will. Are there any 3rd party tools to get around it?