# Storing text that has overflown in js var

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I realise this is a bit of an odd question as it's slightly contradictory but I'd like to be able to hide text that doesn't fit into a div. That much is easy but then I need to take the text that is hidden and store it in a js variable so that i can make it visible on a button click so for example:

```
<html>
<body>
      <div style = "height:10px;width:50px;word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden">
            <p id = "text">Text that is too big for div</p>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var overflow = /*equates to overflow of div*/
$(document).click(function(){
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = overflow
})
```

Something like that.

Comment: Is something like this? you https://jsfiddle.net/sxt37d1b/

Comment: No. I need to replace the current visible text with the text that is not visible. its a cosmetic thing. Thanks anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown

Comment: no that's a completely different question and if you had read my js example you'd have understood what i was asking

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get rid of the `overflow: hidden` property on click?

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content'),
    button = document.getElementById('unhide');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    content.style.overflow = 'visible';
});
```

```html
<button id="unhide" type="button">Unhide</button>
<div id="content" style="height:35px;width:100px;word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden">
    <p>Text that is too big for div. Text that is too big for div. 
       Text that is too big for div. Text that is too big for div. </p>
</div>
```

Comment: No. I need to replace the current visible text with the text that is not visible. its a cosmetic thing. Thanks anyway

Comment: That's not what you said in your question at all. Please edit your question to make it clear what you actually want.