# Protractor - How to verify text selection in dropdown list is not cut off

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a dropdown list where when I select some elements. The text appears cut off in the dropdown box. I need to be able to validate that the text is not cut off in my protractor test.

```
<select class="form-control add_reason_select ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid  ng-invalid-required ng-touched" required="" name="reason_id" ng- options="EntranceReason.Reason for EntranceReason in  selectedTransition.EntranceReasons track by EntranceReason.Id" ng- change="selectReason(selectedTransition.selectedReason)" ng- model="selectedTransition.selectedReason" style="">
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Candidate withdrew" value="1">Candidate withdrew</option>
<option label="Cannot meet applicant salary requirements" value="2">Cannot meet applicant salary requirements</option>
<option label="Conflict of interest" value="3">Conflict of interest</option>
<option label="Did not meet pre-employment requirements" value="11">Did not meet pre-employment requirements</option>
<option label="Does not meet minimum qualifications" value="12">Does not meet minimum qualifications</option>
```

I am using mobile emulation in a Chrome browser of iPhone 5. And the text for some of these drop down selections appears cut off once selected.

For example using a iPhone 5 emulation. If I select **Does not meet minimum qualifications** from the dropdown list. What is actually visible is "**Does not meet minimum qualific**". 
*Depending on which mobile emulation I use, more or less text is cut off.*

I can select the selected element and check it as I have done below in my protractor test.

```
var el = element(by.model('selectedTransition.selectedReason')).$('option:checked');
expect(el.getText()).toEqual('Cannot not meet pre-employment requirements');
```

But this is not not actually reading the visible text but instead is reading the element value which matches the expect statement and passes. How can I verify if the visible text is cut off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor is designed and meant to be used for *functional end-to-end testing* in the browser.

Testing visual aspects of an application is much more difficult because:

- the behavior of the UI controls, the UI effects heavily depend on the browser, browser version, resolution, device, operating system
- it is likely to be changed
- it has a higher probability of failures (because of timing, cursor position, current browser/window size etc)
- difficult to maintain

That said, it would probably still depend on the importance and value of things under test and I can imagine use cases where I would check the visual effects on a page in e2e tests.

---

> How can I verify if the visible text is cut off?

You cannot generally solve it through Selenium WebDriver API and, hence, Protractor directly, but look into checking `clientWidth`, `scrollWidth`, `offsetWidth`, `innerWidth` properties ([related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown)). You can access these attributes using [`getAttribute()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) and [`getCssValue()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getCssValue).