# add tooltip to element which has css text-overflow:ellipses

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, ember.js

I have dynamic text which is loaded in table. 
I want to add popup/tooltip if the text has the css text-overflow:ellipses.

How can I fetch those td only which has the longer text than the width of column.

```
Ember.$('*').filter(function() {
            return Ember.$(this).css('text-overflow') === 'ellipsis';
        }).each(function(elm){
});
```

I tried above code to get the td which has text-overflow: ellipsis.  But in elm I am getting number. I need complete element of td.

Comment: Why don't you give `title` property to all `td` components?

Comment: Wouldn't all divs have `text-overflow: ellipsis` set to them?

Comment: Would this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown​?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('selector').each()` passes the Index and the the Element to the callback. This is why you're just seeing a number. See more:

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Try this:

```
Ember.$('*').filter(function() {
  return Ember.$(this).css('text-overflow') === 'ellipsis';
}).each(function(ind, elm){
  // do things to elm now
});
```

This may give you more than just `<td>` elements, so be careful. May add:

```
return Ember.$(this).find("td").css('text-overflow') === 'ellipsis';
```

Hope that helps.