# How to get the text when it's out of its own div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I am wondering if there is any way with Javascript to get a text when it's out of its own `<div>`. For example if a text is made of 3 sentences, and the last one is only halfy displayed, is there a way to get the entire last sentence, or the first word that isn't displayed with JavaScript ?

Example :

**HTML**

```
<div>loooooong loooooong text. Second sentence. Third sentence</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  max-width: 60px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: you mean to show the hidden text?

Comment: @zabusa I think OP wants to put the hidden text inside a js variable.

Comment: Yes @FedericoklezCulloca that's what I would like to achieve

Comment: `div.innerText` will get all of the text within the div, regardless of whether it is displayed on the page or not.

Comment: @allnodcoms Thank you, but I actually want to get only the part that is hidden if it's possible

Answer (score 3):

To get all the text:

```
var node = document.getElementsByClass('div')[0];
var fulltext = node.textContent; // gets all textual content, hidden or not
```

To get the text displayed:

```
var vistext = node.innerText; // gets only text displayed on page (despite my comment!)
```

Hidden text is then `fulltext` - `vistext`

```
var hiddentext = fulltext.substr(vistext.length);
```

Should do the trick...

Comment: Thank you @allnodcoms for your help. But with this, fulltext and vistext are exactly the same, so hiddenttext is an empty string. But more than half of the text is actually visible so it's not really working for me

Comment: Sorry @br.julien, I got the idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213147/difference-between-text-content-vs-inner-text).
I'll have another think... ;o)

Answer (score 0):

using Jquery

```
if ($('#div-id')[0].scrollWidth >  $('#div-id').innerWidth()) {
    //Text has over-flowed
}
```

reference :
[Detect if text has overflown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown)