# How to detect when textContent has overflowed its parent

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events, whitespace

**Needs:**
I need a trigger for when the textContent of a button has overflowed it's button width.

**Question:**
Is there any concise/clever way to detect when textContent has overflow'd its parent?

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/LmVmzG)

**UPDATED:** Looks like this will solve my problem.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <button>a normal button</button>
   <button>tiny</button>
   <button class="parent">
     <div class="child">a rhhh, really wide button lskdfjlasdkfj lksjd flaksjd flaskdjf lkj</div>
   </button>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;

  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
}
button {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

**JS:**

```
const child = document.querySelector('.child');
console.log(child.scrollWidth, 'child');

const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
console.log(parent.clientWidth,'parent');
```

Normal:
[image: normal]

Trigger:
[image: trigger]

Note:
*I cannot rely on scroll bars. (UPDATED sorta use scrollbars)*

Comment: again the same code :p you want to detect this on resize ?

Comment: maybe one of these can be helpful : https://www.google.com/search?q=detect+overflow+with+js+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXx7bW7uTaAhVMalAKHeaqD9oQrQIIMSgEMAA&biw=1600&bih=794

Comment: I found this topic which can be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406843/detect-if-text-has-overflown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the link I provided you in my comment, here is a working snippet:

```js
$("button").each(function() {
  if ($(this)[0].scrollWidth > $(this).innerWidth()) {
    console.log("Overflow!");
  } else {
    console.log("It's ok.");
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 20px;
}

button {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Added for test */
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>a normal button</button>
  <button>tiny</button>
  <button>a rhhh, really wide button</button>
</div>
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how reliable this is, and it's layout thrashing, but it worked for me:

```
function isButtonOverflowing ( button ) {
    var oldHeight = button.offsetHeight;
    button.style.whiteSpace = 'normal';
    var newHeight = button.offsetHeight;
    button.style.whiteSpace = '';
    return oldHeight !== newHeight;
}
```